# C# Login using MySQL Database - Could not find specified column in results

Tags: c#, mysql, authentication

I am trying to create a login for users which is connected to a MySQL database. When I try logging in on the form I am greeted with the error "**could not find specified column in results: password**" I have some idea it may be because of my DataReader but unsure how to fix.

```
    public class Security
    {
        public static string HashSHA256(string value)
        {
            var sha256 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256.Create();
            var inputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(value);
            var hash = sha256.ComputeHash(inputBytes);

            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (var i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string strConnect = "Server=***.***.***.**;Port=3306;Database=cpr_users;Uid=********;Pwd=********;";
            using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(strConnect))
            using (MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand())
            {
                selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cpr_users.cpr_user_info WHERE username=@User and password=@Password";
                selectCommand.Connection = myConn;
                selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@User", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text; 
                selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text; 
                myConn.Open();
                MySqlDataReader myReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                var hashedPW = Security.HashSHA256(txtPassword.Text);
                var stored = myReader["password"].ToString();
                Int32 count = (Int32)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                if (count == 1 & hashedPW == stored)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful");
                }
                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplication of Username and Password... Access Denied");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and/or Password");
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I am still learning so help is appreciated and if possible an explanation :)

Comment: You need to something like the following 
`while (myReader.Read()){ }` then assing your variables to the myReader variables It would also help if you would step thru the code and tell us the exact line that it error's on if the recommended suggestion does not solve your issue and or other issues arise after making the necessary changes

Comment: I hope you will read this. http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php  It discusses password validation in a php context but contains ideas about password salting that work across language stacks. To handle salted password validation in compliance with security best practice, your `SELECT COUNT(*)` approach won't work; you need to retrieve the hashed/salted password from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your select command doesn't return the column password, so you can't read it.
But in reality you don't need to read it back.
Supposing that you store (as you should) the hash of the password, then pass directly the hash.
If you call ExecuteScalar and this method returns not null and > 0 then you are sure that your user has correctly identified itself

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strConnect = "Server=***.***.***.**;Port=3306;Database=cpr_users;Uid=********;Pwd=********;";
        using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(strConnect))
        using (MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            selectCommand.CommandText = @"SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                         FROM cpr_users.cpr_user_info 
                                         WHERE username=@User and password=@Password";
            selectCommand.Connection = myConn;
            selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@User", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text; 
            selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = Security.HashSHA256(txtPassword.Text);
            object result = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
            if (result != null)
            {
                int count = Convert.ToInt32(result);
                if(count > 0) 
                   MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful");
                else
                   MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and/or Password");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and/or Password");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Of course, you can't have two identical usernames. The field cpr_users.cpr_user_info.username should be defined as an UNIQUE index or as a PRIMARYKEY directly in the datatable schema.

Even if you fix your current code with something like

```
 SELECT * FROM cpr_users.cpr_user_info  WHERE username=@user and password=@password
```

your code will never find the match because you pass the password in clear text when you call the ExecuteReader. This means that, if you find your user then the password is stored in clear text and you cannot compare it with the hashed version returned by `Security.HashSHA256`. As I have said at the beginning, you should store the HASH not the clear text password.

Comment: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` is now the message I'm displayed

Comment: `Toby Cook` are you not understanding or reading comments.. what line is the error happening on.. do you know how to utilize the debugger..?

Comment: @DJKRAZE it is displaying in a message box and the errors are as exactly as I type them here

Comment: I would recommend doing some basic reading on how to formulate a SQL Query as well as when to use Select Count(*)

Comment: Try to temporarily remove the try/catch block and let the exception occur. Visual Studio should show the offending line

Comment: @Steve I removed the Try Catch block and the offending point is `object result = selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();`

Comment: Well that line should not fail if the code is as above. The selectCommand has been initialized in the using block, the return value of ExecuteScalar could be null but I have added a check against null in the following line. I can't explain it

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I'm curious, what was it?

Answer (score 2):

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string strConnect = "Server=***.***.***.**;Port=3306;Database=cpr_users;Uid=********;Pwd=********;";
        using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(strConnect))
        using (MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand())
        {
                var passwordHash = Security.HashSHA256(txtPassword.Text);
                selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cpr_users.cpr_user_info WHERE username=@User and password=@Password";
                selectCommand.Connection = myConn;
                selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@User", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text;
                selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passwordHash;

                myConn.Open();
                int count = (int)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();

                if (count == 1)
                {
                        MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful");
                }
                else if (count > 1) // Consider adding a database constraint to prevent duplicate usernames
                {
                        MessageBox.Show("Duplication of Username and Password... Access Denied");
                }
                else
                {
                        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and/or Password");
                }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}I think you need to call Read() on your MySqlDataReader object



    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    try
    {
        string strConnect = "Server=***.***.***.**;Port=3306;Database=cpr_users;Uid=********;Pwd=********;";
        using (MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(strConnect))
        using (MySqlCommand selectCommand = new MySqlCommand())
        {
            // You need to select all the records instead of COUNT(*)
            selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM cpr_users.cpr_user_info WHERE username=@User and password=@Password";
            selectCommand.Connection = myConn;
            selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@User", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text; 
            selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Password", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtPassword.Text; 
            myConn.Open();
            MySqlDataReader myReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
            // If there is a record   
            if(myReader.Read()) 
            {
                var hashedPW = Security.HashSHA256(txtPassword.Text);
                var stored = myReader["password"].ToString();
                Int32 count = (Int32)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                if (count == 1 & hashedPW == stored)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful");
                }
                else if (count > 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Duplication of Username and Password... Access Denied");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Username and/or Password");
                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: @TobyCook I updated my answer. You need to select * to get the columns instead of just selecting the count (count(*))

Comment: why select * when they only need to query on 2 columns.. that's not very optimal select on the needed columns is always a better approach

Comment: Yes, I'll agree with that. The comment to select * was more out of my laziness.

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure, but my guess is that you are trying to get a column from a result set where it doesn't exists.

If you run your query with the correct info instead of *****

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cpr_users.cpr_user_info WHERE username=***** and password=******
```

you will get a result similar to this:

> Count(*) 
>          1

So when you call:

> var stored = myReader["password"].ToString();

It's trying to get a Column named 'password' but the only column in your result set is 'Count(*)'.

If you really need the count(*) function you may try:

```
SELECT password, COUNT(*) FROM cpr_users.cpr_user_info WHERE username=***** and password=****** group by password;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not return the "password" field. You are returning just a number, because of the Count(*), that is the number of records that match the criteria.

So, first you retrieve the number of users:

```
selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cpr_users.cpr_user_info WHERE username=@User";
selectCommand.Connection = myConn;
selectCommand.Parameters.Add("@User", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = txtUsername.Text; 
myConn.Open();
Int32 count = (Int32)selectCommand.ExecuteScalar();

if (count != 1)
   //message
```

After that, you retrieve the password:

```
selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT password FROM cpr_users.cpr_user_info WHERE username=@User";
var myReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
if(myReader.Read()) 
{
    var stored = myReader["password"].ToString();
    //do the rest of comparison here
}
```

The question is that a better approach is to ensure that you will NEVER have TWO or more users with the same "user id" in the database. If you ensure that (is the usual) you don't have to check how many users where returned with the "count".

Another point is that is best to send the passord and let the database (via stored proc) to check if the pass is the right one for the user.